# errors populating fields of a detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along with the Big Nerd Ranch ios book, chapter 11. It uses a table view in the ItemsViewController to display a list of items and if you click on an item it transfers control to a DetailViewController that shows the details about the individual item. The DetailViewController.xib has outlets for these fields declared in the header file DetailViewController.h

```
  __weak IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *serialNumberField;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *valueField;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
```

The application worked fine up to a point. If i clicked on an item, the new view would open but the fields were empty. Therefore, the tutorial introduced us to a way to have the fields populated with the values of each item. After introducing this new code to populate the fields, the application crashes with the following errors once I click on an item to view its details

```
2014-02-12 07:18:30.720 Homepwner[3180:a0b] -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89ef8c0
2014-02-12 07:18:30.724 Homepwner[3180:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89ef8c0'
```

Based on the code excerpts below can you explain why the application might be crashing when I click on one of the items in the list to open it in the detail view?

This is the code we are given to populate the fields
**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [nameField setText:[item itemName]];
    [serialNumberField setText:[item serialNumber]];
    [valueField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [item valueInDollars]]];

    // Create a NSDateFormatter that will turn a date into a simple date string
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // Use filtered NSDate object to set dateLabel contents
    [dateLabel setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[item dateCreated]]];

    // Change the navigation item to display name of item
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:[item itemName]];
}
```

In **ItemViewController.m**, we added the middle three lines in this function so that the DetailViewController has its item before `viewWillAppear:` gets called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    BNRItem *selectedItem = [ items objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `nameField` property is initialized through a NIB/Storyboard, the most likely reason for the problem that you are seeing is an incorrect connection done in the Interface Builder. It appears that the `nameField` outlet is connected to the parent of `UITextEdit`, as opposed to the `UITextEdit` itself.

Removing and re-creating the `nameField` property should fix the problem. First, remove the property from the code. Then, control-drag from the text field into the `DetailViewController`'s class extension inside `DetailViewController.m`, and name the property `nameField`.